# How to rename column as dataframe name in list?

Tags: r

Hello so I was able to rename a list of dataframes using,

```
names(Final_mixed_list)[1:12] <- sprintf("genome_%d", 1:12)
```

each dataframe has its own name as genome_1, genome_2 and so on

Now I was trying to rename the second column "Names" in each of the dataframes of my lists as their dataframe name "genome_1 instead of Names for the genome_1 list and genome_" for the Genome_2 list and so on.

Each of the dataframes have the same column names "COG" and "Names" and the data and number of rows vary but they all have the same two columns

I tried using lapply along with colnames but instead i got my dataframe deleted using the following

```
final_mixed_list2 <- lapply(seq_along(Final_mixed_list), function(i) {colnames(Final_mixed_list[[i]])[2] <- sprintf("genome_%d", 1:12)})
```

and I got a new list where all of my values were deleted and only genome1 to 12 values were present

My expected result is to keep the dataframes intact like before but to change the Names column with their respective dataframe name genome_1 , genome_2 and so on.

Comment: Its best to include a small example dataset in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I like `imap` for something like this.

```r
library(tidyverse)

#example
df_list <- list(genome_1 = tibble(Name = "genome_1", val = 9),
                genome_2 = tibble(Name = "genome_2", val = 10),
                genome_3 = tibble(Name = "genome_3", val = 15))

df_list
#> $genome_1
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   Name       val
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 genome_1     9
#> 
#> $genome_2
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   Name       val
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 genome_2    10
#> 
#> $genome_3
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   Name       val
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 genome_3    15

#solution
df_list |>
  imap(\(dat, genome) rename(dat, "{genome}" := Name))
#> $genome_1
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   genome_1   val
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 genome_1     9
#> 
#> $genome_2
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   genome_2   val
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 genome_2    10
#> 
#> $genome_3
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   genome_3   val
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 genome_3    15
```